# Can one set title in google script

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function doGet() 
{
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Hello, world!</b>');
}
```

I tried to use `<title>` in the html form, used that in place of "Hello, world!" but it remains the same, the app looks funny with google script url on title.

---

[image]

---

Please help me to add title to the app.

Comment: `function doGet() {
  var h =  HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Hello, world!');
  h.setTitle('My Test App');
  return h;
}`

Answer (score 11):

use [setTitle()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#settitletitle).

```
function doGet() 
{
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Hello, world!')
         .setTitle('Hello Title');
}
```